# Pass a value between views

Tags: jquery-mobile, parameter-passing

I have a list of items of the same type (let's say guests) and i display them in a listview. By clicking on the line I would be able to edit the single element. All the elements have the same editing mask, so i would like to call the same page and pass a parameter.
The only solution that i found it's:

```
<a href="edit-page" onClick="setParameter(32)">Element 32</a>
```

But actually I update the edit view on beforepageshow so in this case I have 2 different methods that run independently to archive this goal.

I was wondering if there is an elegant solution.

Thanks,
Cesare

Comment: it's just html and js on client side. Anyway, it's iOS + PhoneGap + jQueryMobile

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a get parameter?

ie: `href="edit-page?id=32"`

Comment: That is a nice idea. Remember about `progressive enhancement`. Make your site work with pure html (moreover: in your case it's the easiest way)